# How to sort value in Default API country Listing?

Tags: magento2.3.3, magento2.3.4

There is default API's of country listing in magento 2 i.e **directoryCurrencyInformationAcquirerV1** & route URL GET
**/V1/directory/currency**.

The output of this API.

```
[{
        "id": "AD",
        "two_letter_abbreviation": "AD",
        "three_letter_abbreviation": "AND",
        "full_name_locale": "Andorra",
        "full_name_english": "Andorra"
    },
    {
        "id": "AE",
        "two_letter_abbreviation": "AE",
        "three_letter_abbreviation": "ARE",
        "full_name_locale": "United Arab Emirates",
        "full_name_english": "United Arab Emirates"
    },
    {
        "id": "AF",
        "two_letter_abbreviation": "AF",
        "three_letter_abbreviation": "AFG",
        "full_name_locale": "Afghanistan",
        "full_name_english": "Afghanistan"
    },
    {
        "id": "AG",
        "two_letter_abbreviation": "AG",
        "three_letter_abbreviation": "ATG",
        "full_name_locale": "Antigua & Barbuda",
        "full_name_english": "Antigua & Barbuda"
    },
    {
        "id": "AI",
        "two_letter_abbreviation": "AI",
        "three_letter_abbreviation": "AIA",
        "full_name_locale": "Anguilla",
        "full_name_english": "Anguilla"
    },
    {
        "id": "AL",
        "two_letter_abbreviation": "AL",
        "three_letter_abbreviation": "ALB",
        "full_name_locale": "Albania",
        "full_name_english": "Albania"
    },
    {
        "id": "AM",
        "two_letter_abbreviation": "AM",
        "three_letter_abbreviation": "ARM",
        "full_name_locale": "Armenia",
        "full_name_english": "Armenia"
    },
    {
        "id": "AN",
        "two_letter_abbreviation": "AN",
        "three_letter_abbreviation": "ANT",
        "full_name_locale": null,
        "full_name_english": null
    },
    {
        "id": "AO",
        "two_letter_abbreviation": "AO",
        "three_letter_abbreviation": "AGO",
        "full_name_locale": "Angola",
        "full_name_english": "Angola"
    },
    {
        "id": "AQ",
        "two_letter_abbreviation": "AQ",
        "three_letter_abbreviation": "ATA",
        "full_name_locale": "Antarctica",
        "full_name_english": "Antarctica"
    },
    {
        "id": "AR",
        "two_letter_abbreviation": "AR",
        "three_letter_abbreviation": "ARG",
        "full_name_locale": "Argentina",
        "full_name_english": "Argentina"
    },
    {
        "id": "AS",
        "two_letter_abbreviation": "AS",
        "three_letter_abbreviation": "ASM",
        "full_name_locale": "American Samoa",
        "full_name_english": "American Samoa"
    },
    {
        "id": "AT",
        "two_letter_abbreviation": "AT",
        "three_letter_abbreviation": "AUT",
        "full_name_locale": "Austria",
        "full_name_english": "Austria",
        "available_regions": [{
                "id": "102",
                "code": "BL",
                "name": "Burgenland"
            },
            {
                "id": "99",
                "code": "KN",
                "name": "Kärnten"
            },
            {
                "id": "96",
                "code": "NO",
                "name": "Niederösterreich"
            },
            {
                "id": "97",
                "code": "OO",
                "name": "Oberösterreich"
            },
            {
                "id": "98",
                "code": "SB",
                "name": "Salzburg"
            },
            {
                "id": "100",
                "code": "ST",
                "name": "Steiermark"
            },
            {
                "id": "101",
                "code": "TI",
                "name": "Tirol"
            },
            {
                "id": "103",
                "code": "VB",
                "name": "Vorarlberg"
            },
            {
                "id": "95",
                "code": "WI",
                "name": "Wien"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

And i have override this API's but unable to sort by full_name_english key. Is there any one who can sort full name english so that united arab emirates will be according to ascending order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the country model class using the plugin.

Put the below code in your custom module di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Directory\Model\CountryInformationAcquirer">
        <plugin name="CountryList" type="[vendor]\[module]\Plugin\CountryList"/>
    </type>
```

Create plugin folder inside [vendor]->[module] & create CountryList.php

then, Put the below code & play with $result return by default country list API.

```
<?php

namespace Vendorname\modulename\Plugin;

class CountryList
{
    public function afterGetCountriesInfo(\Magento\Directory\Model\CountryInformationAcquirer $subject, $result) {
        $data = [];
        foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
            $data[$key]['id'] = $value->getId();
            $data[$key]['two_letter_abbreviation'] = $value->getTwoLetterAbbreviation();
            $data[$key]['three_letter_abbreviation'] = $value->getThreeLetterAbbreviation();
            $data[$key]['full_name_locale'] = $value->getFullNameLocale();
            $data[$key]['full_name_english'] = $value->getFullNameEnglish();
            $regions = [];
            if (!empty($value->getAvailableRegions())) {
                foreach ($value->getAvailableRegions() as $keyr => $region) {
                    $data[$key]['available_regions'][$keyr]['id'] = $region->getId();
                    $data[$key]['available_regions'][$keyr]['code'] = $region->getCode();
                    $data[$key]['available_regions'][$keyr]['name'] = $region->getName();
                }
            }
        }
        usort($data, function ($item1, $item2) {
            return $item1['full_name_english'] <=> $item2['full_name_english'];
        });
        return $data;
      }
}
```